# What is causing the "this" pointer to be null within my constructor?

Tags: c#, reference, null, this

I am new to c# and use it with unity3D. When I use the `new` keyword to initialize an object it seems to have null in it even though the object is created and the constructor executes:

```
public class Wire
{
  public Wire()
  { 
    System.Console.WriteLine("constructor executed");
    System.Console.WriteLine(this);
  }
}

Wire wire1 =new Wire();
System.Console.WriteLine(wire1);
```

The output is:

> constructor executed
>   null
>   null

I need to store the reference in a list but now I can't. How can I solve this problem?

---

ok the actual code is

```
public class SharedResources
{    
    public static Dictionary< GameObject , Wire> dict = 
       new Dictionary<GameObject, Wire>();
    //...
}

public class Wire
{
    public GameObject x = y.y; 
    //y.y is another gameobject so its a normal copy constructer

    public Wire()
    { 
        print("constructor executed"); 
        // print is provided from unity package
        SharedResources.dict.Add( x,this);
    }
}
```

and in the main i have

```
Wire wire1 = new Wire();
if ( SharedResources.dict.ContainsKey( wire1.x) )
{
    print("ok"); // it does print that!!
    if ( SharedResources.dict[wire1.x] !=null )
        print("its not null");
    else
        print("its null");
}
```

output:

> constructor executed
>   ok
>   its null

Comment: There is zero chance the code you give will produce that result. Something else is going on that cannot be seen here.

Comment: please post the full code of your Wire class

Comment: I'm guessing you've overridden `ToString`... `WriteLine` simply calls `ToString` on the provided arguments, your `Wire` class must do something in `ToString`.

Comment: public Wire() 
{ System.Console.WriteLine("constructor executed"); } 

Wire wire1 =new Wire(); 
System.Console.WriteLine(wire1); 
}

this should be or the last 2 rows are in a function. 

*** suggestion ***

Comment: using your exact code. That's not what I see. you should see an empty line when the object is null and the fully qualified type name if it's not null

Comment: @dwaik If your sample code is to be believed, there is no reason why your output should think it's null.  Unless `wire1.x` is different from the `x` used in the constructor, or the hashing calculation doesn't return the same result?

Comment: i found the solution... the Wire class is inhereting from MonoBehaviour comes from unity3d package.. whenever you inheret from that class "this" will be always null dont know why

Comment: Look upon my edits and be amazed.  Also, your "solution" is still incorrect.  `this` cannot be null except in the most extreme circumstances.

Comment: @will i used the same code without inhereting from MonoBehaviuor it worked well ("this" returns the actual object) and its fine for me, but when i inheret it does return null try it yourself if you have unity and if you have explanation for that please let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible.

The `this` keyword can never be a `null` reference, a constructor can never return a null reference, and calling `Console.WriteLine` with a null reference doesn't display "null", it displays an empty line, i.e the same as `Console.WriteLine(String.Empty)`.

You can get that behaviour if you override the `ToString` method to return the string `"null"`:

```
public class Wire {

  public Wire() {
    System.Console.WriteLine("constructor executed");
    System.Console.WriteLine(this);
  }

  public override string ToString() {
    return "null";
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Please Note:**  The code in the question itself is never what the actual code is (as stated in the comments) leading people down the wrong path (the Wire class should be shown to inherit from MonoBehavior).  And the currently accepted answer has nothing to do with what's happening in this case.

The real issue is, the above code inherits from MonoBehavior.  In that case, if you instantiate the class with new it will indeed return `true` for `(this == null)` and false for `(this != null)`.  Of course you will still be able to access members of this because the object isn't actually `null`, it is just the `==` and `=!` operators which are overloaded.

What is going on is that in Unity, for any class that inherits from `UnityEngine.Object` (or any subclasses, obviously) it is undefined behavior to instantiated the class via new.  To create such objects you have to use `UnityEngine.Object.CreateInstance`, `MonoBehavior.Instantiate` or some such.  The overloaded `==` / `=!` operators probably check for some flag that is set by these custom instantiate methods.

Answer (score 2):

As the question stands, it is incomplete.

The `this` keyword will never be null because it only has scope inside instance members of a class.  If there is an instance, `this` is not null, so by definition it can never be null.

When you pass an argument into `WriteLine`, it simply calls `ToString` on the argument.  If you pass an argument such as a class reference, it will print out the type name if not overridden.  In your case, it must be overridden in order to return the string literal "null".  Passing a `null` argument such as:

```
string s = null;
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Simply doesn't print anything.

If you want to store the reference in a list, you don't store a string representation of the reference, you store the reference itself:

```
List<Wire> wires = new List<Wire>();
wires.Add(new Wire());
```

**Update:** C# doesn't have a "normal copy constructor" unless you have implemented one yourself.  However, even if you implement one yourself, it creates a different object.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this is happening but when i call :
Debug.Log ("LevelColection constructor " + this);

I get the same result: 
LevelColection constructor null
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)

Edit:
 So the object is not created if you inherit MonoBehaviour. The thing that worked for me was just remove the : MonoBehaviour and it worked like charm. Have a nice day.